# Distribution in random function in Matlab

Tags: matlab, random, distribution

I use random function in matlab to produce an integer between [1, n] with random function. For
example random('unid', n) produce every time a number between [1, n]. What  if I want to change the distribution from uniform to another. How can I indicate to random that i want an
integer between [1, n]??????????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[exprnd](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/exprnd.html) uses exponential distribution. That's the easy way.

Otherwise, AFAIK, you'd use the theory to implement the random generation and the use of the distribution on it.

Comment: ok yeah. I think i ve got somewhere a implementation of rayleigh transform . But i ve just hoped to find other distributions transformation code implementations. Thanks for the answer!